# Multi threading andd save csv file

Tags: python, csv

i try get requeses multi threading and save to data
but when the multi threading in use itss not save the csv
what can do ?
Must add time.sleep? He can not do the
saving and at the same time I would be happy for help thanks
this the script

```
import requests
import csv
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import time
import json
url_list = []

with open('bookslinks.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # urls = list(reader)
    for row in reader:
        url_list.append(row[0])

def download_file(url):
    string = url
    say = "="
    after = string[string.index(say) + len(say):]
    bugeycheck = "https://xxxx/" + after + "data=" + after
    j = json.loads(requests.get(bugeycheck, timeout=20,stream=True).content);
    dataname = "bbbb/" + str(after) + "bbbb" + ".txt"
    print(j["xx"])
    with open('beneficiary.csv', 'a') as newFile:
        newFileWriter = csv.writer(newFile)
        newFileWriter.writerow([after, j["xx"]])
    return

start = time()

processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    for url in url_list:
        processes.append(executor.submit(download_file, url))

for task in as_completed(processes):
    print("test")


print(f'Time taken: {time() - start}')
```

the console python when the multi threading use

```
#####
false
false
falsefalse
false
####
false = add to csv file
false = add to csv file
falsefalse = add only one to csv file
false = add to csv file
```

Comment: First, you need to have a threading lock; otherwise the subsequent thread will not access the csv if previous thread has not released. Second, it may be better if you write each result to a list and then once all your threads have finished, then write all the results to csv file. Of course, this would depend on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think write list but the question is about 4000 lists is not a problem ?